# HikaShop: Different Shipping costs on different Payment methods

Tags: joomla

-- HikaShop version -- : 1.5.6
-- Joomla version -- : 2.5.1

I have many categories in my system. And two payment methods lets say C and D. When a user buys a product from category A OR B and selects C as payment method the shipping cost will be FREE. And when the user buys from category A OR B and selects D as payment method the shipping cost will be 35.

Is this possible with my current version of Hikashop? Or possible with any updated version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Hikashop often, so I know a bit about its limitations. Payment methods can be restricted to shipping methods, shipping methods can be associated to warehouses, and products are associated with a warehouse. So under all versions of Hikashop what you are trying to achieve is not really possible. The only thing I can think of is to create a discount/coupon and under the restrictions, restrict it to a payment method.